# How to prevent someone adding me to a board without my permission?

Tags: trello, permissions

How to prevent someone adding me to a board without my permission?
There is no 'report abuse' link in the email which informs me someone has added me to a group without my permission.

There are only links to more spam, and trello preferences. It is a genuine email from Trello, the spam link is what Trello provides (eg 6 ways to get more out of Trello etc etc etc)

Why does Trello allow this?

Comment: "Why does Trello", or any other app, " allow something" is a opinion based question on this site, and it's a second question. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Trello doesn't provide a option to prevent being added into a board.

But they have a "Report Abuse" thing:

- Click on Trello profile in upper right hand corner
- Click "Help"
- Click "Send us a message"
- Select from the topic dropdown "I need to report abusive behavior"

They should respond rather quickly.